# Is there a low-level difference between int[large][small] or int[small][large] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, multidimensional-array, jvm

This question will probably require some compiler knowledge to answer. I am currently working on a project where I will be creating an array that may be either

```
int[2][veryLargeNumber]
```

or

```
int [veryLargeNumber][2]
```

It makes no difference logically but I was thinking that the form (and therefore size) in memory may differ (perhaps the question should be, are the compilers clever enough to rearrange arrays to suit them)?

Comment: It seems that the first option would have less overhead, since it's equivalent to two large 1D arrays, while the second option is equivalent to a large number of small 1D arrays. The first option requires less array instances - the 2D array and 2 1-D array. The second option requires the 2D array instance and many 1-D array instances.

Comment: I don't believe there is one, no. There _would_ be if the second dimension were not specified but here you specify it.

Comment: @Eran no in fact; it is the `multianewarray` which is used when you have a "fixed dimension" multiple array

Comment: If you have a fixed size of 2 and this low level optimization is really important go for a one `int[2N]`, instead of `int[2][N]` or `int[N][2]`.

Comment: It also depends on how are you handling the elements. Depending on what you are doing having a cache-aware disposition may significantly speed up your code (though this is probably a bit less true for java and other high level languages compared to, say, C or C++)

Comment: @fge `multianewarray` provides a shorter bytecode for the all-dims-known case, but it still allocates separate array objects at each level and links them together; see the third paragraph of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.multianewarray

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Java only actually implements single dimensional arrays. It has multi-dimensional types, however two dimensional arrays are actually implemented as an array of arrays.  Each array has an overhead of about 16 bytes.  You are better off with `int[2][x]` to minimise overhead.

You can avoid this issue entirely by using helper methods.

```
final int[] array = new int[2 * veryLargeNumber];

public int get(int x, int y) {
    return array[idx(x, y)];
}

public void set(int x, int y, int val) {
    array[idx(x, y)] = val;
}

private int idx(int x, int y) {
    return x * 2 + y; // or x * veryLargeNumber + y;
}
```

To provide this to yourself, each object hash a unique, generate hashCode which is stored in its Object header.

You can see from http://ideone.com/oGbDJ0 that each nested array is an object in itself.

```
int[][] array = new int[20][2];
for (int[] arr : array) {
    System.out.println(arr);
}
```

prints the internal representation of an `int[]` which is `[I` followed by `@` followed by the hashCode() stored in the header.  This is not as some believe, the address of the object. The address can't be used as the hashCode, as the object can be moved at any time by the GC (unless you have a JVM which never moves objects)

```
[I@106d69c
[I@52e922
[I@25154f
[I@10dea4e
[I@647e05
[I@1909752
[I@1f96302
[I@14eac69
[I@a57993
[I@1b84c92
[I@1c7c054
[I@12204a1
[I@a298b7
[I@14991ad
[I@d93b30
[I@16d3586
[I@154617c
[I@a14482
[I@140e19d
[I@17327b6
```

You can see how much memory is used if you turn off the TLAB with `-XX:-UseTLAB`
https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Performance-Examples/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/memory/ArrayAllocationMain.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long used1 = memoryUsed();
    int[][] array = new int[200][2];

    long used2 = memoryUsed();
    int[][] array2 = new int[2][200];

    long used3 = memoryUsed();
    if (used1 == used2) {
        System.err.println("You need to turn off the TLAB with -XX:-UseTLAB");
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Space used by int[200][2] is " + (used2 - used1) + " bytes%n");
        System.out.printf("Space used by int[2][200] is " + (used3 - used2) + " bytes%n");
    }
}

public static long memoryUsed() {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    return rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();
}
```

prints

```
Space used by int[200][2] is 5720 bytes
Space used by int[2][200] is 1656 bytes
```

Comment: Err no. `multianewarray` :p

Comment: @fge Java has multi-dimensional types, however it is still an array of arrays and those nested arrays have an Object header like all other objects.

Comment: An other interesting point could be performance, if you have a really big array and access it in a tight loop, memory locality could be an issue. For this case (if a profiler shows you there is a performance bottleneck) you can arrange the elements so they are accessed continously. (which may be x*2 + y or y*length + x depending on your control flow.

Comment: The memory address also cannot be directly used as the hash code because 64 bit addresses do not fit in 32 bit integers, and here in 2016, 32 bit JVMs are becoming less and less common.

Comment: @Snowman even in 32-bit JVMs the address cannot be used because objects are moved by the GC and the hashCode of an object cannot change.

Comment: @Falco yes, you can decide what is best based on your access pattern.  Note: multiplying by a power of 2 can be faster than by an arbitrary number, all things otherwise being equal.

Comment: Converting `int[2][lots]` to `int[2*lots]` is a microoptimization that reduces readability. Don't do that!

Answer (score 23):

Interesting question, I ran a simple program

```
int N = 100000000;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int[][] a = new int[2][N];
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + " ms");
```

Which resulted in `160 ms`. Then I ran the other variant

```
int N = 100000000;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int[][] a = new int[N][2];
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + " ms");
```

Which resulted in `30897 ms`. So indeed the first option seems **much** better.

Comment: he is asking about how it is implemented in JNDI ,to understand that which is more usable code. ?? this is not the answer he asked..

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Well to be honest, I think it is an interesting performance observation. And while it may not answer his question directly, it may help in deciding which way to go.

Comment: Interesting,Sher Alams answer supports yours.

Answer (score 11):

```
 int[2][veryLargeNumber]
```

creates two arrays with verlarnumber of items
while

```
 int[veryLargeNumber][2]
```

creates verylargenumber of arrays having two items.

Note: array creation has a overhead. so preferred the first one

Comment: Also, the second option causes more memory fragmentation. Accessing random places in memory is slower.

Answer (score 1):

In short, `int[2][veryLargeNumber]` is the better approach.

The one suggested by Peter (`int[] array = new int[2 * veryLargeNumber];`) is even better, or if memory is your problem, then you can use longs instead of integers (`long[] array = new long[veryLargeNumber];`) and bitwise operators, or better yet, use caching whenever possible.

Beware! The representation `[I@106d69c` in most JDK/JRE distributions (Sun's & Oracle's) is given by `System.identityHashCode()` and it's not *guaranteed* to be unique per each object. So you cannot rely on `System.out.println(array);` to check the unicity of the array object.